# NSURLConnection randomly fails until device reboot

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I have been struggling with an issue where `NSURLConnection` calls instantly fail. The device needs to be rebooted entirely or Flight Mode needs to be toggled on/off to resolve the problem. Restarting the app (swipe up) alone does not help.

Some facts:

-All URLs are HTTPS, TLS 1.2 compatible with Forward Secrecy. There are no issues with ATS and iOS 9. The error has been present since iOS 7 and remains on 9.2.

-No third party frameworks are used by the app. I use only native `NSURLConnection` calls that always work, except for when this odd situation occurs.

-No infrastructure/network issues - other devices on same networks (same WiFi for instance) work in the same app at the same time. Going to/from 3G/Wifi makes no difference.

-I always implement `willCacheResponse` to return `nil`.

-The service is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, so some suggested that it might be a DNS caching issue in case of IP address changes - this seems unlikely to me and should trigger multiple errors at once on different devices, which I have never seen.

-The method called is `didFailWithError`, instantaneously, as if there were no Internet connection on the device at all - all other apps work, however.

-The website that hosts the API used by the app can be browsed with no problems at all times. The website actually makes the same requests to fetch data.

The error code returned is -1003, `kCFURLErrorCannotFindHost`. I've been following a thread on Git dealing with the same issue to no avail. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/967

I tried using `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` for all my requests, but that did not help.

With this information, will anyone care to venture a guess what I might be doing wrong? I added the bounty because I have no idea how to approach this problem - especially because it's so inconsistent. And it is definitely not a legitimate error (that is, that the domain could not be found), as the service is operating fine while this happens on random clients.

I create my request with a static method that looks like this. It's been stripped of some non-public info, but basically it just performs a POST request with JSON data. `[Controller getSQLHost]` just returns a URL - the base domain.

```
+(NSURLConnection*)initiatePOSTwithJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary toURL:(NSString*)urllocation withDelegate:delegate {

    NSMutableDictionary *connectionDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (dictionary) {
        [connectionDictionary setObject:dictionary forKey:@"input"];
    }

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:connectionDictionary options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[Controller getSQLHost] stringByAppendingString:urllocation]];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)[jsonData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    return [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:delegate];

}
```

Comment: @KiritModi While I appreciate you taking time to respond I fail to see what the article has to do with my issue?

Comment: Can you give me URL ?

Comment: I cannot. It requires authentication which I cannot provide. There are no problems with the server.

Comment: It's definitely an issue with the client.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, You can you can calling service using NSURLSession,

Comment: Again this has nothing to do with my issue. I don't use sessions at all. Please read the question again or point out which part is unclear to you.

Comment: Can you post code to show what you're doing? Can you create a minimal app that recreates the problem outside your application?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on my device at all. I've seen it only once in a year and a half, and others see it almost daily. I'll add some code for the NSURLConnection part, hold on.

Comment: Easiest workaround would be to add a retry when the lookup fails. Any external resource calls within the API itself?

Comment: The retry will just fail then? How does that help? No, and nothing like that would give domain connection error on the client side. Edit: not meant to sound rude.

Comment: If you retry, for example 10 times with a 500ms gap, you expect every retry attempt to fail? Would be an interesting test to see if it did. No way of caching the IP address and manually adding the host header to the connection? Point taken about the client receiving the DNS error if the server failed a resource attempt - that would be unlikely.

Comment: @Rots I would expect it to fail all 10 times, yes, as that's what happens if I manually refresh 10 times. Also note that the client does not receive an error - it generates an error. The request never reaches the server.

Comment: assuming you've tried closing the connection, creating a new object, etc. AFNetworking has a Network Reachability Manager which would really help in this case. Aside from a potential bug in `NSURLConnection` which seems unlikely, there's not really a lot of choice for you. Either handle the error returned, and retry/go offline until availability returns, or use a separate library eg: `libcurl`.

Comment: I always create a new object, as you can see in my code example. I cannot retry or go offline as the phone needs to be rebooted before the error goes away...

Comment: I'll have a look at reachability manager in AF. I don't use AF now though - only native calls.

Comment: @nickdnk, was just reading the link to the github post, the author was using Reachability Manager and it seems like it showed as 'available' but still got the same error -1003 and could not connect. Sorry but this looks like it might not solve your problem in that case. Have you considered giving `libcurl` a go? I would be really interested to see if it's even possible to bundle and release with on the appstore.

Comment: @Roth So frustrating this

Comment: Very. To solve it would earn much respect!

Comment: @Ruth I think going to a third party framework would be the wrong direction. I'm trying to narrow down where exactly in the chain of "ask for my domain" to "connect to an IP address" the problem roars its ugly head. I am still assuming it's DNS related, but according to the GitHub thread that might not even be the case.

Comment: @nickdnk, are you having problem with one specific device?

Comment: @Allen - several, but some suffer from it very frequently and most rarely or not at all. Same version of the app across the board. And as I mentioned in the question, the problem has been present on iOS 7 through 9.

Comment: i would try to test out the network first! maybe run a script to connect to your host continuously on your device and computer and compare the result.

Comment: I did. As mentioned in the question I can have two devices on the same wifi. One works fine and the other fails all requests instantly. You can browse the web page from a computer on the same wifi in the mean time. Definitely not an infrastructure problem.

Comment: Also the problem occurs on both cellular network and wifi.

Comment: @nickdnk did you ever figure this out? I think I might be running into the exact same issue.

Comment: @damirstuhec It went after after replacing all network calls with URLSessions. I never experienced it after. NSURLConnection is deprecated anyway. You should write Swift code if at all possible: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnection

Answer (score 0):

Does you delegate implement connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage ? (or respond with YES)

I think the device's keychain is used when this method returns yes which may explain the persisting failure beyond the life time of the running application and why rebooting or otherwise resetting network connectivity "fixes" it.  If an authentication failure has been recognized once, it may linger in the key chain for a little while which would then respond immediately without actually going to the server.

What would cause the authentication to register as a failure in the keychain in the first place may depend on a variety of factors. It could be as simple as a typo in the saved password or more convoluted such as some certificate expiration preventing the SSL layer from establishing a secure link.

Comment: I did not implement this method, no. I use SSKeyChain to retrieve the device token from the keychain every time the app starts. This then becomes part of the request.

Comment: What I understand of this method is that if you don't implement it, the caller assumes that it responds YES and it will go to the keyChain store.   If you're doing your own key chain manipulations this could be interfering and you might want to implement the method to make it respond NO.

Comment: But would that not make every call fail, then? I could try I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating `NSURLConnection`s on the current runloop.  How many are active at any one time? Have you considered using an `NSOperationQueue` so that you don't get bitten by load bugs?

Is your delegate thread-safe?  If not, that could explain the sporadic-ness of the bug.

You say you don't see the problem often, but others do.  Can you borrow their devices and maybe even them and their usage patterns and thus get to see the problem more often?

Comment: Mostly only one call at a time. I don't create more than one request per user action. I cannot borrow their devices. - the problem does not occur frequently enough - also, I wouldn't know what to do as the only logging I can get is error 1003 which tells me nothing. I'm considering moving to NSURLSession, but according to the GitHub thread that doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: Don't know about thread safety. I just followed all the usual guides for NSURLConnection. None of them mention thread safety.